# { [Error: Connection timeout] code: 'ETIMEDOUT' } in nodemailer

Tags: node.js, smtp, cloud9-ide, nodemailer

I'm facing some problems using the nodemailer module in my node.js application at cloud9. A simplified version of my code is

```
      mail_test : function(req, res, next){
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host : "smtp.webfaction.com",
    secureConnection : true,
    port: 465,
    auth : {
        user : "username",
        pass : "password"
    }
}));

    var mailOptions={
        from : "info@feedcourt.com",
        to : "net.nayek@gmail.com",
        subject : "Your Subject",
        text : "Your Text",
/*        html : "<b>HTML GENERATED</b>",
        attachments : [
            {   // file on disk as an attachment
                filename: 'text3.txt',
                path: 'Your File path' // stream this file
            }
        ]*/
    }

    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.end("error");
        }else{
            console.log(response.response.toString());
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            res.end("sent");
        }
    });
  },
```

when I have try to execute it on the server I got an ETIMEDOUT error

```
{ [Error: Connection timeout] code: 'ETIMEDOUT' }
```

my module version is -

```
"nodemailer": "^2.4.2"
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.5.0"
```

I am totally frustrated. please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending email from cloud9 workspaces is not allowed to block spam.
See https://community.c9.io/t/how-can-i-send-email-from-my-app/1262/3 for more details.

Comment: Thank you!. but if i need to send a email using smtp then how to send from cloud9

Comment: you can't do that, since the port is blocked